# How can I create a filled polygon from unordered edge data in MATLAB?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, polygon

I want to create a polygon using edge data (X,Y coordinates of each point of edge) that is **unordered**, and I want to fill that polygon with some color.

Any suggestions how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How is your edge data stored (the number of variables, their sizes, etc.)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your polygon is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_and_concave_polygons), you can just compute the convex hull from the vertices using the function [CONVHULL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/convhull.html) and plot the polygon using the plotting function [PATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html). For example:

```
x = [0 1 0 1];  %# Unordered x coordinates of vertices
y = [0 1 1 0];  %# Corresponding y coordinates of vertices
hullIndices = convhull(x,y);  %# Gives vertex indices running counterclockwise
                              %#   around the hull
patch(x(hullIndices),y(hullIndices),'r');  %# Plot the polygon in red
```

If your polygon is instead *concave*, that becomes trickier. You would have to reorder the edge lines yourself by comparing their end points and ordering them in either a clockwise or counterclockwise fashion.

...but if that sounds like too much work to code up, you can sidestep the issue by creating a [constrained Delaunay triangulation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html) of the vertex points, [find the triangles on the inside of the constrained edges](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.inoutstatus.html), then plot these individual triangles that form the polygon using [PATCH](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html). For example:

```
x = [0 1 0 1 0.5];    %# Unordered x coordinates of vertices
y = [0 1 1 0 0.5];    %# Corresponding y coordinates of vertices
edgeLines = [1 3;...  %# Point 1 connects to point 3
             1 4;...  %# Point 1 connects to point 4
             2 3;...  %# Point 2 connects to point 3
             2 5;...  %# Point 2 connects to point 5
             5 4];    %# Point 5 connects to point 4
dt = DelaunayTri(x(:),y(:),edgeLines);  %# Create a constrained triangulation
isInside = inOutStatus(dt);  %# Find the indices of inside triangles
faces = dt(isInside,:);      %# Get the face indices of the inside triangles
vertices = [x(:) y(:)];      %# Vertex data for polygon
hPolygon = patch('Faces',faces,...
                 'Vertices',vertices,...
                 'FaceColor','r');  %# Plot the triangular faces in red
```

The above will display the polygon with edge lines around each sub-triangle that forms it. If you just want an edge line shown around the outside of the entire polygon, you can add the following:

```
set(hPolygon,'EdgeColor','none');  %# Turn off the edge coloring
xEdge = x(edgeLines).';           %'# Create x coordinates for the edge
yEdge = y(edgeLines).';           %'# Create y coordinates for the edge
hold on;                           %# Add to the existing plot
line(xEdge,yEdge,'Color','k');     %# Plot the edge in black
```

Comment: +1 useful answer. I was thinking of maybe converting the points to polar coordinates and somehow sort by angle..

Comment: @Amro: An interesting idea, but technically it's possible to have a concave polygon with sharp enough bends that it could reverse angular direction, kind of like [this polygon](http://www.gamasutra.com/features/20000210/lander_figure_02.gif).

Comment: I figure out my problem is more complex, but this is greate answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [`patch()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) function. You can do 2-D and 3-D polygons with it.