# Given Polygon and Fix Points, Find the Triangle Meshes

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a polygon, and I want to mesh it. In order to further put constraints on the mesh I get, I will supply a list of fix points ( which must lie inside the polygon) so that they must be connected by the triangle elements generated.

What is the matlab command to do it? I tried [`delaunay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay.html) command, but it can't work on concave polygon because the `delaunay` command will always return me a list of elements that encompass a convex area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you want to use is [`DelaunayTri`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html), and you would follow these steps to do it:

- Create a list of the edge points in your polygon.
- Take all of the vertex points of your polygon and combine them with the additional fixed points you want to include inside the polygon.
- Create a constrained triangulation (as I've illustrated in other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700522/matlab-create-delaunay-triangulation-with-opening/1701496#1701496) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4391186/how-can-i-create-a-filled-polygon-from-unordered-edge-data-in-matlab/4392611#4392611)).
- As you noted, this will create a triangulation of the convex hull (even if you have a concave polygon), so you would have to remove triangles outside of the constrained edges using the method [`inOutStatus`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.inoutstatus.html) (also illustrated in the answers linked above).

Here's some sample code:

```
polygonVertices = [0 0;...  %# Concave polygon vertices
                   0 1;...
                   1 1;...
                   0.5 0.5;...
                   1 0];
polygonEdges = [1 2;...  %# Polygon edges (indices of connected vertices)
                2 3;...
                3 4;...
                4 5;...
                5 1];
otherVertices = [0.5.*rand(5,1) rand(5,1)];   %# Additional vertices to be added
                                              %#   inside the polygon
vertices = [polygonVertices; otherVertices];  %# Collect all the vertices
dt = DelaunayTri(vertices,polygonEdges);  %# Create a constrained triangulation
isInside = inOutStatus(dt);  %# Find the indices of inside triangles
faces = dt(isInside,:);      %# Get the face indices of the inside triangles
```

And now the variables `faces` and `vertices` can be used to [plot the meshed polygon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html).

### Working with older versions of MATLAB...

Looking through the [archived version documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html) (**note:** a MathWorks account is required to do so), one can see that [`DelaunayTri`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html) first appeared in version 7.8.0 (2009a). Prior to that, the only built-in functionality available for performing 2-D Delaunay triangulation was [`delaunay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay.html), which was based on [Qhull](http://www.qhull.org/) and was thus unable to support constrained triangulations or triangulations of non-convex surfaces.

The newer [`DelaunayTri`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunaytri.html) uses [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/). As such, one option for users of versions older than 7.8.0 is to [create MEX-files](http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1600/1605.html) to interface CGAL routines in MATLAB. For example, if you're faced with triangulating a concave polygon, you can create a MEX-file to interface one of the [convex partitioning routines in CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.2/doc_html/cgal_manual/Partition_2/Chapter_main.html#Section_9.3) in order to break the concave polygon into a set of convex polygons. Then [`delaunay`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/delaunay.html) could be used to triangulate each convex polygon, and the final set of triangulations grouped into one larger triangulation of the concave polygon.

Comment: my matlab version ( 7.6.0) doesn't have DelaunayTri and `inOutStatus` method. Is there a substitude for `inOutStatus`?

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: I'd have to look around a bit to see what was available for that version. If I find a way to do it using older functions, I'll update the post.

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: I added my best suggestion for working with older MATLAB versions to the answer. Hope it helps.